# Woocommerce checkout add information after country

Tags: woocommerce, field, addition, checkout

maybe you can help me. I am looking for a way to add an extra field or div-container with additional information after the country selection in the checkout section.
"for shipping to other countries, please contact us at..."

is there a way to do this in the functions.php?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about functions.php, but if you don't mind to use jQuery you can add some code to your scripts

```
$('#billing_country_field').after('<span>for shipping to other countries, please contact us at...</span>');
```